# Куда можно класть свои самописные методы в laravel?

Tags: laravel

У меня есть метод который выводит статусы ошибок. Где в laravel правильней всего его расположить ? Куда покласть его ?

Answer (score 0):

В ларавел есть класс app/Exceptions/Handler.php который обрабатывает все exceptions. Там лучше всего обрабатывать исключения. Можешь создать цепочку методов для проверки необходимых тебе исключений. Вот пример того как можно это реализовать:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  \Exception $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return $this->checkValidationException($request, $exception);
}

/**
 * Check for validation exception.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param \Exception $e
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
private function checkValidationException($request, $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ValidationException && $request->is(RouteServiceProvider::SSO_PATTERN)) {
        return response()->json([
            'code' => $e->status,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'errors' => $e->errors()
        ], $e->status);
    } elseif ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Token is Expired'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    } elseif ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Token is Invalid'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    } elseif ($e instanceof JWTException) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    return $this->notFoundHttpExceptionHandler($request, $e);
}

/**
 * NotFoundHttpException handler.
 *
 * @param $request
 * @param $e
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
private function notFoundHttpExceptionHandler($request, $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json([], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return $this->authorizationExceptionHandler($request, $e);
}

/**
 * authorizationExceptionHandler handler.
 *
 * @param $request
 * @param $e
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
private function authorizationExceptionHandler($request, $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        return response()->json([], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```